# Getting specific Array items in one row (PostgreSQL)

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Here's my problem:

I have a table with 4 columns (type = array, one-dimension) with values like:

```
   ID        c1             c2           c3

   1      {1, 2, 3}    {10, 20, 30}   {100, 200, 300}
   2      {4, 5, 6}    {11, 22, 33}   {111, 222, 333}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to get a result like the following:

```
   select ID, c1, c2, c3 from t1 where c3 = 200 (<---- pseudo-statement!)
```

Result:

```
   1, 2, 20, 200
```

or

```
   select ID, c1, c2, c3 from t1 where c3 = 333
```

Result:

```
    1, 6, 33, 333
```

So what I want is to get the corresponding values of the value in the where-statement.

Is there a way to get a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edit1: simplified, Edit2: wider scope)

Solutions for **any** array-length. Also returns all hits, even at multiple positions in one or more arrays at the same time.

If you know the **fixed length** of the one-dimensional array, you can hard-code it in [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES), for the **simplest and fastest solution**:

```
SELECT id, c1[i], c2[i], c3[i]
FROM   tbl, generate_series(1, 3) i
WHERE  c3[i] = 200;
```

---

If all arrays in `c3` have the **same unknown length**, you can generalize at very little cost:

```
SELECT id, c1[i], c2[i], c3[i]
FROM   tbl, generate_subscripts((SELECT c3 FROM tbl LIMIT 1), 1) s(i)
WHERE  c3[i] = 200;
```

Note that I use the convenient function [`generate_subscripts()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS) here.
For a greater subscripts than the upper limit, array elements are just `NULL` and drop out of the query.

---

If the **unknown length** of the array in `c3` actually **varies**, you can generalize some more, at a higher cost:

```
SELECT id, c1[i], c2[i], c3[i]
FROM   tbl
FROM   tbl, generate_series(1, (SELECT max(array_upper(c3, 1)) FROM tbl)) s(i)
WHERE  c3[i] = 200;
```

---

Finally, for **non-standard array subscripts** in addition, the same could be done like this:

```
SELECT id, c1[i], c2[i], c3[i]
FROM   tbl
     , generate_subscripts((SELECT c3 FROM tbl
                            ORDER  BY array_length(c3,1) DESC LIMIT 1), 1) s(i)
WHERE  c3[i] = 200;
```

---

#### Instant testbed:

```
WITH tbl (id, c1, c2, c3) AS (
    VALUES
     (1, '{1, 2, 3}'::int[], '{10, 20, 30}'::int[], '{100, 200, 300}'::int[])
    ,(2, '{4, 5, 6}', '{11, 22, 33}', '{111, 222, 333}')
-- un-comment to test 333 in all positions of c3 and varying array length
--  ,(3, '{7, 8, 9, 10}', '{14, 25}', '{333, 333, 333, 333}')
    )
SELECT id, c1[i], c2[i], c3[i]
FROM tbl
    ,generate_subscripts((SELECT c3 FROM tbl
                          ORDER  BY array_length(c3,1) DESC LIMIT 1), 1) s(i)
WHERE  c3[i] = 333;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use generate_series to produce a cross join of your table and all indexes of your arrays (here it will be 1,2,3) :

```
select *
from (
  select yourtab.id
  ,      yourtab.c1[tidx.idx]
  ,      yourtab.c2[tidx.idx]
  ,      yourtab.c3[tidx.idx]
  from yourtab
  cross join generate_series(1, 3) tidx(idx)
) t(id, c1, c2, c3)
where c3 = 333
```

Note the asumption that each array will always have 3 elements.

Comment: Really an elegant solution! Thank you!